# Problem with image source scraping in loop using Python BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I try to scrape image source, all I get is a thing starting with "data:type" and base64 encoding of the image.
All I want to get is **URL** of the image.

I tried to check i I can just condition it and skip this and then extract the URL, but it doesn't work, it just skips entire image.

Please help.

```py
def get_product_data(url):
    response = http.request("GET", url)
    check_conn_errors(response.status)
    bs_data = Bs(response.data, "html.parser")
    product_html = bs_data.find("div", {"class": PRODUCT_DATA_CLASS_NAME})
    imgs = product_html.find_all("img")
    img_link = ""

    for i in range(len(imgs)):
        if imgs[i]["src"].startswith("/"):
            img_link = PRODUCTS_URL_PREFIX + imgs[i]["src"]
            break
        elif imgs[i]["src"].startswith("http") \
                or imgs[i]["src"].startswith("www") \
                or imgs[i]["src"].startswith(DEALER_NAME.split(' ')[0].lower()):
            img_link = imgs[i]["src"]
            break

    if img_link == "":
        print("this doesn't work")

#TODO: standardize description scraping

    desc_html = product_html.find_all("div", {"class": DESCRIPTION_CLASS_NAME})
    desc = ""

    for desc_part in desc_html:
        desc += desc_part.text.replace('\n', '&#xD;').replace('\r', '&#xD;').replace('<br/>', '&#xD;').replace('</br>', '&#xD;')
    return [desc, img_link]
```

Comment: Could you share the ```url``` or HTML structure of the page so that we can identify the problem?

Comment: Yeah  I get the feeling the base64 encoded image is whats in the html file rather than the URL, bs4 can only read whats there. Please link to the source of the file you are working on.

Comment: https://sylveco.pl/produkt/sylveco-zestaw-do-pielegnacji-wlosow-niskoporowatych/ i want to extract main product image

Comment: I want to note that I'll have to insert the image to a woocommerce product, can it be in this notation? If yes, do I have to do anything with it or convert it in any way?

Answer (score 1):

To extract product main image you can select `<a>` with `class="woocommerce-main-image"`):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://sylveco.pl/produkt/sylveco-zestaw-do-pielegnacji-wlosow-niskoporowatych/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one(".woocommerce-main-image")["href"])
```

Prints:

```
https://sylveco.pl/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/niskoporowate.jpg
```